# Flutter video player check if video is mute

Tags: flutter

I have a small video player app and a draggable bar that allows to adjust the volume of video. However, some videos do not have any sound (mute), in this case I want to disable that bar.

How is it possible to check this?

I am using `video_player: ^2.2.5` package https://pub.dev/packages/video_player to display the videos.

In my widget I use `_videoPlayerController.value.volume` which returns `1.0` both for mute and videos with sound, which is volume of the controller but not video itself.